# How to insert datagridview record into mysql database using foreach

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

This code runs fine Values from the dataGridview are also saved succesfully but after saving the entered values in database a null row is also added in the tabl

```
    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)// picks data from dataGridview                
        {

            try   // MySql connection
            {
                string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=markcreations; Uid=root; Pwd=admin";
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice", row.Cells["Invoice"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobOrder", row.Cells["jobOrder"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTime", row.Cells["Date"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientCode", row.Cells["Client Code"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", row.Cells["Client Name"].Value);

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO record(invoice, jobOrder, dateTime, clientCode, clientName)VALUES(@invoice, @jobOrder, @dateTime, @clientCode, @clientName)";
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an empty row in the DataGridView, probably the last one, which is used for a new row. That row has null values for each column and if you dont check for it, it would insert the NULL's.

You can use `row.IsNewRow`, to check for the new row.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks buddy it worked.
>
> Here is the Correct code along with row.IsNewRow

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=markcreations; Uid=root; Pwd=admin";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)                   
        {
         try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice", row.Cells["Invoice"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobOrder", row.Cells["jobOrder"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTime", row.Cells["Date"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientCode", row.Cells["Client Code"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", row.Cells["Client Name"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobName", row.Cells["Job Name"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flexQuality", row.Cells["Flex Quality"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sizeLength", row.Cells["Size Length"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sizeWidth", row.Cells["Size Width"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", row.Cells["Rate"].Value);
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO record(invoice, jobOrder, dateTime, clientCode, clientName, jobName, flexQuality, sizeLength, sizeWidth, rate)VALUES(@invoice, @jobOrder, @dateTime, @clientCode, @clientName, @jobName, @flexQuality, @sizeLength, @sizeWidth, @rate)";
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
    }
```